# Как называется конструкция funcName: function() {...}

Tags: javascript

Уже который раз встретилась с таким синтаксисом:

```
$('#exampleModal').reveal({
    close: function () { console.log("модальное окно начинает скрываться"); },
    closed: function () { console.log("модальное окно только что скрылось"); },
});
```

Как он называется и где о нем почитать?

Comment: таким это каким?  передается объект как параметр в функцию.... у которого ключи - функции, которые вызываются в определенное время..... в какое - определяется плагином `reveal` внутри своей логики

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данная конструкция

```
{
    close: function () { console.log("модальное окно начинает скрываться"); },
    closed: function () { console.log("модальное окно только что скрылось"); },
}
```

Называется: [Литерал объекта](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). С помощью такой нотации можно создавать объекты и инициализировать их поля.

В данном случае создается объект с двумя полями: `close`, `closed` - каждое из полей является функцией.

Comment: Если ставите минус, аргументируйте свои действия